# Trouble hosting project via Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, hosting

When I start my project via Heroku I am getting an error saying that "app" is not defined. I have logged "app" and get data back so I do not know why this is happening. Has anyone had this issue before? Here are the errors and the code:

```
State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626715+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/listen.js:3
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626744+00:00 app[web.1]: app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}...`));
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626745+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626745+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626751+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: app is not defined
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626752+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/listen.js:3:1)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626752+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626764+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-05-05T22:16:42.626765+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-05-05T22:16:42.652119+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-05-05T22:16:42.652547+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-05-05T22:16:42.661700+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! be-nc-news@1.0.0 start: `node listen.js`
2021-05-05T22:16:42.661926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-05-05T22:16:42.662168+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-05-05T22:16:42.662387+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the be-nc-news@1.0.0 start script.
2021-05-05T22:16:42.662587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 

app.js:

const express = require("express");
const apiRouter = require("./routes/apiRouter");
const app = express();
const {
  handlePsqlErrors,
  handleServerErrors,
} = require("./errorHandlingFunctions/errorFunctions");

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api", apiRouter);

app.use(handlePsqlErrors);
app.use(handleServerErrors);

module.exports = app;

listen.js:

const app = require("./app");

console.log(app);

const { PORT = 9090 } = process.env;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

Comment: Hi Joe. Welcome among those who failed (or computers failed them…?). There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. Having been around when Unicode was becoming a thing in code editors, I would check for “invisible characters” on that line. I doubt it’s your issue, but in such seemingly bizarre cases, it’s worth a shot. Checking this depends on your editor and OS. Sadly, some editors say they can show invisible characters, but they really don’t – they just highlight tabs, spaces and new lines. If your editor has hex mode or hex dump, that’s a certain way to know.

Comment: I think that may have been it! I ended up deleting everything and retyping it all out and it works. Thanks a lot!